# How can I create a dev. environnement using Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, git, node.js

I'm not sure if it's the right place to ask this question. So let me know, if it's not.

I'm building a front end app with VueJs. I actually use 2 computer. I use the first computer as a "server" (just a computer that is always on) and and the other one I use it to code.

The server have a VSCode that is always open that always run my front end app. I use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to this server when I need to code/build/run. I use Azure Dev Ops as a Git solution.

But all this setup is not the best way to work. It's kinda annoying to connect to the server and let vscode always open.

What I want to know is : Is it possible to create a better dev. environnement? For example, what I want to do is to be able to work from VSCode on my "dev's computer" and whenever I push something in Azure DevOps, my server re-build and re-run my app.

How should I start ? Can you give me any documentation to help me? I couldn't find anything in the net (maybe because I'm doing something wrong in my research)

Comment: Of course is absolutely possible. #1 Is your two computers  a cloud machines on azure? #2 Is your vue standard? I mean just need the : npm install && npm run build and npm run start ?

Comment: @JRichardsz No, my computers are physical station

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to learn the basis with generic technologies and then use Azure.

### The basic and modern devops flow

[image]

- Devops admin configure the webhook or trigger to connect the git server with the ci,cd,devops sever
- Devops admin configure the job with steps required to build the application.
- Developer push some source code (java, php, c#, nodejs, etc)
- Your git platform/server (bitbucket, gitlab, github, azure, etc) detects this event and perform an http post request to your webhook url (preconfigured) sending it a json payload with important information related to detected event.
- You ci,cd,devops,etc server receives the http post request and using a json parser extract some important or common values used in devops automation like : repository name, branch name, commit author, commit message, etc
- Your ci,cd,devops,etc server launchs a preconfigured job. At this point you could start, launch or invoke any technology. (java, php, c#, nodejs, etc) required to build the application

More details here:

- https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/devops-with-git-and-jenkins-using-webhooks
- https://jrichardsz.github.io/devops/configure-webhooks-in-github-bitbucket-gitlab

### Devops flow with open source

- git server: github, bitbucket, gitlab, etc
- ci,cd,devops server: jenkins, Harness CI,etc. Check [this](https://harness.io/blog/continuous-delivery/best-jenkins-alternatives/) and [this](https://devops.com/11-open-source-devops-tools-we-love-for-2021/)

### Devops flow with Azure

- git server: Azure Repos: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/repos/
- ci,cd,devops server: Azure Devops: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/ Azure Pipelines: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/

Steps

- Devops admin configure the pipeline trigger to connect the **azure repos** with the **azure devops/pipeline sever**: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers
- Devops admin configure the **azure-pipeline** with steps required to build the application: https://github.com/bdellegrazie/vue-hello-world/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml
- Developer push some source code (java, php, c#, nodejs, etc)
- **Azure repos** detects this event and perform an http post request to **Azure Devops** sending it a json payload with important information related to detected event.
- **Azure Devops server** receives the http post request and starts the interpretation of azure-pipeline.yml
- **Azure Devops server** launches all the steps preconfigured in the azure pipeline, in your case: npm install, npm run build and npm run start

### Docker

I advice you Docker to skip the azure-pipeline.yml creation. With docker you app will be deployable on any server (gcp,aws,digital ocena, azure, bare metal, etc) in the galaxy. With azure-pipeline.yml just on Azure. Check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604539/how-to-use-docker-in-the-development-phase-of-a-devops-life-cycle/60780840#60780840

### Kubernetes

If you achieve the previous steps, you could start the use of kubernetes

### Enterprises environments

If your company has the recommended environments like: staging, testing, uat, pre-prod, etc you will need a configuration management. Check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54220775/how-to-use-variable-substitution-in-frontend-js-applications-like-backend-applic/54271114#54271114